# Como inserir arrays dentro de objetos em angular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net

Digamos que eu tenho um objeto veiculo que possui os seguintes atributos convertendo minha classe c# para Json:

```
 {
  "UsuarioId": 0,
  "TipoId": 0,
  "MarcaId": 0,
  "ModeloId": 0,
  "VersaoId": 0,
  "Quilometragem": 0,
  "AnoFabricacao": 0,
  "AnoModelo": 0,
  "Combustivel": null,
  "Cor": null,
  "Placa": null,
  "VsCustom": null,
  "Valor": 0.0,
  "Troca": false,
  "inPublico": false
}
```

Porém esse veículo também terá fotos e vídeos dos quais eu utilizo a ng-file-upload e converto para base64. Além disso esse veículo tem itens opcionais que são carregados em um ng-repeat com checkboxes onde o usuário irá selecionar os itens opcionais. Até aí ok!
O problema mesmo é na hora do post. Se eu fizer tudo separado funciona, mas gostaria de inserir o array de fotos e array de itens dentro do objeto. Já tentei com enviar o objeto desta forma:

```
$scope.postVeiculo = function () {
    var v = {
        Marca: $scope.veiculo.Marca,
        Modelo: $scope.veiculo.Modelo,
        Versao: $scope.veiculo.Versao,
        ....
        Files: [$scope.files], <- Esse é o array de fotos
        Items: [$scope.items] <-- esse é o de itens opcionais
    };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'minhaUrl',
        data: $.param(v),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })
    .success(function (data, status) {
        ...tratamento se ok
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        ...tratamento do erro
    });
};
```

Já fiz várias tentativas com push, splice, mas o response sempre me retorna Referência não definida para instância de objeto. As vezes é frustante trabalhar com angular e projetos ASP.NET MVC e a documentação não é lá muito esclarecedora. Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Se tá te retornando um erro do C# é melhor você debugar por lá e ver a causa do erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo seu exemplo, basta remover os colchetes:

```
$scope.postVeiculo = function () {
    var v = {
        Marca: $scope.veiculo.Marca,
        Modelo: $scope.veiculo.Modelo,
        Versao: $scope.veiculo.Versao,
        ....
        Files: $scope.files, //<-- Se $scope.files já um array, não precisa de colchetes
        Items: $scope.items //<-- Se $scope.items já um array, não precisa de colchetes
    };
```

Comment: Obrigada Thiago, eu resolvi  o problema inicializando o objeto $scope.novo = {
        UsuarioId: null,
        TipoId: null,
        MarcaId: null,
        ModeloId: null,
        VersaoId: null,
        Quilometragem: null,
        AnoFabricacao: null,
        AnoModelo: null,
        Combustivel: null,
        Cor: null,
        Placa: null,
        VsCustom: null,
        Valor: null,
        Troca: false,
        inPublico: false,
        Files: [],
        Items: []
    }; aí funcionou!